# Can't restore purchases using Appcelerator ti.storekit

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appcelerator

I have created an app using the ti.storekit module.  I used the example code from GitHub: https://github.com/appcelerator-archive/ti.storekit/tree/master/ios

I am able to buy my non-consumable product successfully with a sandbox account, but if I delete the app, and install again, I am not able to restore my purchase.  Clicking the Restore button gives me the "no purchases to restore" message.  However, if I try to Buy the product again, it tells me I've already purchased it.

Any help or example code where you've implemented this successfully?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Facing something similar.

Comment: I didn't really find a sure-fire solution, but I think it was just acting goofy with my test id.  It seems to work fine for normal id's, just acts weird when testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really find a sure-fire solution, but I think it was just acting goofy with my test id. It seems to work fine for normal id's, just acts weird when testing.